# How do I fix "the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied" when cloning a struct with generics and a function pointer?

Tags: function, pointers, rust, clone

I'm writing a function that will create a menu interface in the terminal. To use the function, it needs to be passed a `Vec<menu_option>`

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct menu_option<'a, T> {
    pub command: &'a str,
    pub description: &'a str,
    pub action: menu_option_action<'a, T>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum menu_option_action<'a, T> {
    sub_menu(Vec<menu_option<'a, T>>),
    callback(fn(state: T) -> T),
    leave,
}
```

When I design the menu, it can have multiple levels and there can be repeats of a `menu_action`. Namely, each layer has a "leave"/"return":

```
// In my actual code I construct a vector of `menu_option`s
fn example() {
    type StateType = i32;
    let mut state: StateType = 88;
    let leave_option: menu_option<&mut StateType> = menu_option::<&mut StateType> {
        command: "l",
        description: "leave",
        action: menu_option_action::leave,
    };

    let a = leave_option.clone();
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for struct `menu_option<'_, &mut i32>` in the current scope
   --> src/lib.rs:24:26
    |
2   | pub struct menu_option<'a, T> {
    | -----------------------------
    | |
    | method `clone` not found for this
    | doesn't satisfy `menu_option<'_, &mut i32>: std::clone::Clone`
...
24  |     let a = leave_option.clone();
    |                          ^^^^^ method not found in `menu_option<'_, &mut i32>`
    |
    = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut i32: std::clone::Clone`
            which is required by `menu_option<'_, &mut i32>: std::clone::Clone`
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
    = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
            candidate #1: `std::clone::Clone`
```

How do I fix this?

I tried searching online and couldn't find a solution, at least, not one that worked for me (what I found was old Rust, I think)

I don't know what stops the clone because the only use of the `T` type is a function pointer which I thought was cloneable.

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when you implement `Clone` yourself on `menu_option` & `menu_option_action`. By default, since your struct/enum has a type parameter, the macro expansion of the `#[derive(Clone)]` attribute will restrain the clone implementation for your type to `T: Clone`.

In your case, not only is this requirement not needed, but it is also very unlikely to be ever respected (e.g. `&mut T` does not implement `Clone`). By implementing `Clone` by hand, you can get rid of the `T: Clone` requirement and it works!

Note that function pointers implement `Copy` which is why the `menu_option_action::callback(*f)` works:

```
type StateType = i32;

pub struct menu_option<'a, T> {
    pub command: &'a str,
    pub description: &'a str,
    pub action: menu_option_action<'a, T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Clone for menu_option<'a, T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        menu_option {
            command: self.command.clone(),
            description: self.description.clone(),
            action: self.action.clone(),
        }
    }
}

pub enum menu_option_action<'a, T> {
    sub_menu(Vec<menu_option<'a, T>>),
    callback(fn(T) -> T),
    leave,
}

impl<'a, T> Clone for menu_option_action<'a, T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            menu_option_action::sub_menu(sub) => menu_option_action::sub_menu(sub.to_vec()),
            menu_option_action::callback(f) => menu_option_action::callback(*f),
            menu_option_action::leave => menu_option_action::leave,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state: StateType = 88;
    let leave_option: menu_option<&mut StateType> = menu_option {
        command: "l",
        description: "leave",
        action: menu_option_action::leave,
    };

    let a = leave_option.clone();
}
```